# Замена в html-коде при помощи JavaScript или jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть текст, например такой и он может встречаться несколько раз: `%%text%%`
Как при помощи JavaSrcipt/jQuery заменить ВСЕ вхождения этого текста на:
`<span class="class_name"></span>`

Comment: использовать замену по регулярному выражению

Comment: teran, регулярные выражения для меня темный лес. буду благодарен за кусок кода

Comment: Ты хотя бы html выложи...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получите элемент, в котором может встречаться подобный шаблон (в примере я взял `body` целиком), после чего обратитесь к свойству `innerHTML`, чтобы получить содержимое тега, потом при помощи замены по регулярному выражению замените все вхождения `%%text%%` на другую подстроку:

```js
var source = document.body.innerHTML;
var changed = source.replace(/%%text%%/g, '<span class="class_name"></span>');

document.body.innerHTML = changed;
```

```html
%%text%% Что-то еще %%text%%
<div>%%text%% внутри div</div>
<em><strong>%%text%% во вложенном теге</strong></em>
```

А если вы имели в виду, что строка, подлежащая замене не строго равна `%%text%%`, то стоит уточнить, какие значения могут находиться между знаками процента (только буквы, или буквы и цифры, может быть символы нижнего подчеркивания и т.п.).

Comment: нет, именно строго равна, вы все правильно поняли. код полностью работает, большое спасибо! как здесь принято благодарить?

Comment: @Evgeny принято нажимать на стрелочку вверх слева от ответа, если считаете его полезным, и на галочку (тоже слева от ответа), если он решил вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Если надо заменить ЛЮБОЙ текст внутри %% %%, тогда так:

```js
const toReplace = $('.to-replace');


for(let i = 0; i < toReplace.length; i++){
  
  $(toReplace[i]).text($(toReplace[i]).text().replace(/%%[^%]*%%/g, '<span class="class_name"></span>'));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="to-replace"> Тут меняем  %%text text%%
</div>
<div class="none"> Тут останется %%text%%  
</div>
<div class="to-replace"> Нечего менять изменений
</div>
<div class="to-replace"> Несколько вхождений %%text%% %%aaa%% %%12-23%%
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

По всему сайтку поиск организовывать не эффективно, давайте ограничимся для примера div-ами (их может быть несколько!) с классом "to-replace", и воспользуемся функцией replace с нужным нам регулярным выражением. Тогда получим:

```js
const toReplace = $('.to-replace');


for(let i = 0; i < toReplace.length; i++){
  
  $(toReplace[i]).text($(toReplace[i]).text().replace(/%%text%%/g, '<span class="class_name"></span>'));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="to-replace"> Тут меняем  %%text%%
</div>
<div class="none"> Тут останется %%text%%  
</div>
<div class="to-replace"> Нечего менять изменений
</div>
<div class="to-replace"> Несколько вхождений %%text%% %%text%% %%text%%
</div>
```

Comment: на сколько это "не эффективно". просто я не знаю, в каких элементах может находиться строка. поэтому по ходу придется производить поиск вообще во всем body. Подошло решение пользователя "smellyshovel", но смущает ваш комментарий о "не эффективности". На сколько это будет тормозить работу сайта?

Comment: Зависит от объема информации на странице